# clearing errors on Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, sdl

I'm new to using Eclipse. I'm trying to write some C++ code in it with the CDT but I can't figure out how to tell it to rebuild manually. I did a little test program and accidentally put SDL_EVERYTHING instead of SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING in SDL_Init args. I changed it to the correct name and saved but when I right clicked on the project and chose run as c++ application it said I still had that error. In fact that line is still underlined in red saying it can't find SDL_EVERYTHING even though it's been changed.

Does anyone know how to force eclipse to rebuild or how to clear these errors? This seems trivial but I haven't found anything online about how to get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have CDT installed on this computer at the moment, but as I recall you can clean and build a project using options under the project menu.

[For more information](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Building_C.2FC.2B.2B_Projects)